# How to properly define SQLAlchemy backrefs so that they can be reflected?

Tags: python, python-3.x, orm, sqlalchemy

Let's assume we have the following code in some Models.py file:

```
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Persons'
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True, nullable=False)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

class House(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Houses'
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True,nullable=False)
    OwnerID = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    TenantID = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)

    __table_args__ = (
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['OwnerID'],
            ['Persons.ID'],
        ),
        db.ForeignKeyConstraint(
            ['TenantID'],
            ['Persons.ID'],
        ),
    )

    OwnerBackref = db.relationship('Person', backref='OwnerBackref', lazy=True, foreign_keys=[OwnerID])
    TenantBackref = db.relationship('Person', backref='TenantBackref', lazy=True, foreign_keys=[TenantID])
```

And we want to reflect these models using the automap base, so we have this code in another module called Database.py:

```
Base = automap_base()
engine = create_engine(DB_CONNECTION, pool_size=10, max_overflow=20)
db_session = scoped_session(sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine))
Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
Person = Base.classes.Persons
House = Base.classes.Houses
```

Now, when I import House in some other module I want to be able to do this:

```
h = db_session.query(House).first()
print(h.OwnerBackref.Name)
print(h.TenantBackref.Name)
```

But instead I get an error saying that those 2 backrefs do not exist and instead a field called 'persons' gets added to my House object but the problem here is that it links only 1 (either the Tenant either the Owner). By this I mean that if I do this:

```
print(h.persons.Name)
```

It will only print the Name either for the respective Tenant either for the Owner leaving me with no way of accessing the informations for the other one. (Note here that the names that I set to the backrefs are nowhere to be found)

***So, my question is how can I use the backrefs I created to access my desired informations ?*** Am I doing something wrong here ?

Answer (score 0):

The error in your code is that you are using `foreign_keys=` to define the relationship between the tables but you are passing the local key name not the foreign key name to the function. For your code you cannot use `foreign_keys=` to define the relationship within the House model as there is only one possible foreign key `Person.ID` but two possible local keys `House.OwnerID` and `House.TenantID`. The `primaryjoin=` argument should be used instead to specify this.

```
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Persons'
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

class House(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Houses'
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    OwnerID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Persons.ID'), nullable=False)
    TenantID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Persons.ID'), nullable=False)

    Owner = db.relationship('Person', backref='HousesOwned', primaryjoin='House.OwnerID == Person.ID')
    Tenant = db.relationship('Person', backref='HousesOccupied', primaryjoin='House.TenantID == Person.ID')
```

If you placed the relationship statements in in the Person model rather than the House model then you could use either `foreign_keys=` or `primaryjoin=` to define the relationship. The following code will result in exactly the same relationships as in the previous code.

```
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Persons'
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    Name = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False)

    HousesOwned = db.relationship('House', backref='Owner', foreign_keys='[House.OwnerID]')
    HousesOccupied = db.relationship('House', backref='Tenant', foreign_keys='[House.TenantID]')


class House(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'Houses'
    ID = db.Column(db.Integer,primary_key=True)
    OwnerID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Persons.ID'), nullable=False)
    TenantID = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('Persons.ID'), nullable=False)
```

Comment: I tried both you suggestions but unfortunately they don't seem to work for me. 
The first one behaves the same as I described in the question: a field called 'persons' gets created for my House object, so if I do something like:
h = models.db_session.query(models.House).first()
print(h.persons.ID)
It will only print the ID of the Tenant or the ID for the Owner.
For the second version I get a 'houses_collection' field in my Peron object but it gives me an empty list:
p = models.db_session.query(models.Person).first()
print(p.houses.collection)